# How to convert list of dictionaries in a string column to different rows and columns in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Here's a sample for string column, I would want to split this string column into multiple columns based on the key values of dictionary and if there are more keys, I want to make them into different rows.

```
<column1>: "val",
<column2>: "for each user:[{"id":1,
"Publisher":null,
"type":0,
"Identity":{
"Id":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"sid":"134567890"},
"roles":[],
"permissions":[],
"name":ABC},
{"id":1,
"Publisher":null,
"type":0,
"Identity":{
"Id":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"sid":"134567890"},
"roles":[],
"permissions":[],
"name":ABC}]"
```

I want to trim initial string "for each user:" and create columns for **id, publisher, type, Identity.Id, Identity.sid, roles, permissions, name** and since there are two dictionaries in the above sample, I want to insert the second item into a new row.

I also want column1 in the output

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
datatable(message:string) ["for each user..."] // complete the full payload
| parse message with "for each user:" dict:dynamic
| mv-expand dict
| project dict.id, dict.publisher, dict.type, dict.Identity.Id //... add the rest of the properties you're interested in
```

**update** - based on your update to the question:

````
print message = ```<column1>: "val",
<column2>: "for each user:[{"id":1,
"Publisher":null,
"type":0,
"Identity":{
"Id":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"sid":"134567890"},
"roles":[],
"permissions":[],
"name":"ABC"},
{"id":1,
"Publisher":null,
"type":0,
"Identity":{
"Id":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"sid":"134567890"},
"roles":[],
"permissions":[],
"name":"ABC"}]"```
| parse message with * '<column1>: "' column1 '"' * '<column2>: "for each user:' dict:dynamic '"'
| mv-expand dict
| project dict.id, dict.publisher, dict.type, dict.Identity.Id, column1
````

| dict_id | dict_publisher | dict_type | dict_Identity_Id | column1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 0 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | val |
| 1 |  | 0 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | val |

Comment: thank you but what if I need an additional column apart from dict column? ``` | parse message with "for each user:" dict:dynamic, <column1>``` doesn't work right?